# Считывание данных из массива в JSON

Tags: c#, json

Есть данные в JSON:

```
{
    "direction": "desc",
    "on_page": 30,
    "success": "ok",
    "pages": 6,
    "domain": "site.ru",
    "order": "uid",
    "box_limit": 1000,
    "accounts": [
        {
            "fname": "Молчанова",
            "birth_date": null,
            "login": "molchanova@site.ru",
            "fio": "Молчанова  Юля"
        },
        {
            "fname": "Прекрасная",
            "birth_date": null,
            "login": "torg382@site.ru",
            "fio": "Прекрасная  Елена"
        },
        {

            "fname": "Никитина",
            "birth_date": null,
            "login": "nikitina@site.ru",
            "fio": "Никитина  Елена"
        },
        {
            "fname": "Кутищева",
            "birth_date": null,
            "login": "kutisheva@site.ru",
            "fio": "Кутищева  Мария"
        },
    ],
    "offset": null,
    "found": 30,
    "total": 160,
   "page": 1
}
```

Я пытаюсь прочитать фамилии, но почему-то цикл читает лишь первую фамилию:

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(result);
foreach(var s in rss["accounts"])
{
    return (string)s["fname"];
}
```

Как прочитать все фамилии?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Цикл читает только первую фамилию, потому что вы сразу возвращаете результат из метода. Тут нужно либо в цикле заполнять список, либо воспользоваться `yield return`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"{
            'direction': 'desc',
            'on_page': 30,
            'success': 'ok',
            'pages': 6,
            'domain': 'site.ru',
            'order': 'uid',
            'box_limit': 1000,
            'accounts': [
                {
                    'fname': 'Молчанова',
                    'birth_date': null,
                    'login': 'molchanova@site.ru',
                    'fio': 'Молчанова  Юля'
                },
                {
                    'fname': 'Прекрасная',
                    'birth_date': null,
                    'login': 'torg382@site.ru',
                    'fio': 'Прекрасная  Елена'
                },
                {

                    'fname': 'Никитина',
                    'birth_date': null,
                    'login': 'nikitina@site.ru',
                    'fio': 'Никитина  Елена'
                },
                {
                    'fname': 'Кутищева',
                    'birth_date': null,
                    'login': 'kutisheva@site.ru',
                    'fio': 'Кутищева  Мария'
                },
            ],
            'offset': null,
            'found': 30,
            'total': 160,
           'page': 1
        }";
        var ac1 = GetAccounts(json);
        var acLinq = GetAccountsLinq(json);

        foreach (var account in GetAccountsYield(json))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(account);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetAccountsYield(string jsonStr)
    {
        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

        foreach (var s in rss["accounts"])
        {
            yield return (string)s["fname"];
        }
    }

    private static List<string> GetAccountsLinq(string jsonStr)
    {
        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

        var accounts = from account in rss["accounts"]
            select account["fname"].Value<string>();

        return accounts.ToList();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetAccounts(string jsonStr)
    {
        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
        var accounts = new List<string>();

        foreach (var s in rss["accounts"])
        {
            accounts.Add((string)s["fname"]);
        }

        return accounts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант с Linq, думаю, тоже был бы уместен

Comment: добавил вариант с Linq

Comment: t3mplar Скажите как мне отобразить все в LIstbox-e, интерессует вариант с Linq. Спасибо!

Comment: не совсем понял вопрос. у `ListBox` есть свойство `DataSource`. вот ему и присваивайте список, что у вас получился на предыдущем шаге